# Could not print the BMI table as per expectation

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I just finished a program that calculates a table of body mass index. But, I couldn't print the table as per expectation. I tried to change the for loop location but it gave me the same result.
If you execute the code you will understand me.
The actual output:

[image: the output execute:]

The expected output:

[image: the expected output execute]

My Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float kg;
    float m;
    float col;
    float bmi;
    float cm;

    printf(" BMI");
    for(kg=50; kg <= 105 ;kg=kg+5) {
        printf("  %.0fkg",kg);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(cm=140; cm <= 220 ;cm=cm+5) {
        printf("%.0fcm\n",cm);
    }
    for(col=1; col <= 12 ;col++) {
        for(m=1.4; m <= 2.2 ;m=m+0.05) {
            for(kg=50 ;kg <= 105 ;kg=kg+5) {
                bmi = kg/(m*m);
                printf(" %.1f",bmi);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note for future editing questions, the title should _summarize_ your question and include the most important question. Don't make your title the first half of the first sentence and then continue the sentence in the question. Title and question body should be grammatically independent.

Comment: After you have printed the first column, you cannot go back. Therefore, you have to print the row label (height) as first thing in the outer loop. You might also want to look into width specification of `printf` formats.

Comment: And post the output and expected output here itself.

Comment: @MOehm I tried but it gave me another random table

Answer (score 1):

You want to print a BMI table like so:

```
   BMI          50kg      55kg      60kg      65kg       ...

 140cm         25.51     28.06     30.61     33.16       ...
 145cm         23.78     26.16     28.54     30.92       ...
 150cm         22.22     24.44     26.67     28.89       ...
 155cm         20.81     22.89     24.97     27.06       ...
 160cm         19.53     21.48     23.44     25.39       ...
   ...           ...       ...       ...       ...
```

When you print to a terminal, you must print top to bottom, left to right. When something was printed, there's no way to go back. So you must structure your loops accordingly:

- print "BMI"
- print all mass labels
- print all data rows:

  - print mass label
  - print BMI for all mass and the current height

Other things to note:

- Your outer loop over `col` is useless, because you break out of it after the first iteration.
- If you want your table to lok tidy when printed with a fixed-width font, you should specify field widths for the `printf` formats. For example `%10g` wil pad the number with spaces to the right so that it takes up 10 spaces. (If the number is too large, it will overflow the field width, though.)

Putting all this into practice, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int m;                  // mass in kg
    int h;                  // height in cm

    printf("%10s    ", "BMI");
    for (m = 50; m <= 105; m = m + 5) {
        printf("%8dkg", m);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (h = 140; h <= 220; h += 5) {
        printf("%8dcm    ", h);

        for (m = 50; m <= 105; m = m + 5) {
            double bmi = 10000.0 * m / (h * h);

            printf("%10.2f", bmi);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(I've used integers for the discrete masses and heights, because they are easier to iterate over. When calculating the BMI, they must be converted to floating-point numbers in order to get the fractional part of the BMI. The expression `10000.0 * m` makes the numerator a float and ensures that the divison is a flaoting-point divison. You must give the scaling factor as a floating-point literal with a decimal point, however.)

Comment: it's the same if you execute your code it's not like i want ....... i didn't get it

Comment: The example doesn't do _exactly_ what you want. I had written my example before you posted your desired output. In principle, the output is what you want, though. I use wider field widths, which makes the lines wrap around on a narrow display. You can easily adapt this solution by making minro changes in the [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) formats. If you can't be bothered to do even that, look at milevyo's solution; it's closer to what you want.

Answer (score -1):

you have to print line-by-line, not column-by-column.

print the top header, then each line with its header

```
the top header

[BMI][...][...]
```

then lines

```
[xx cm] [....] <--- line data
  ^_________________<line header
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float kg;
    float m;
    float col;
    float bmi;
    float cm=140.0;

    printf("BMI    ");
    for(kg=50; kg<=105; kg=kg+5) {
        printf("%.0fkg  ",kg);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //for(col=1; col<=12; col++) {
    for(m=1.4; m<=2.2; m=m+0.05) {
        printf("%.0fcm  ",cm);
        for(kg=50; kg<=105; kg=kg+5) {
                bmi=kg/(m*m);
                printf("%.1f  ",bmi);
            }
            cm+=5;
            printf("\n");
        }
   //     break;
   //}
    return 0;
}
```

---

output:

[image]

Comment: you are the best thanx

Comment: @MahmoudAbosaleh: Now that you have been spoonfed your desired solution, why not acknowledge milevyo's work and accept or even upvote the answer?

Comment: @MOehm actually  I am new in this site so when I upvote  to some one it will not appear to the general .... if there any way to do that please tell me